# How to get rid of extra cells generated by grid?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

In order to make my site responsive using Tailwind CSS, I set my classes to change from two columns to two rows when it passes some defined breakpoints

```html
<section id="hero" class="pt-12 pb-12 bg-yellow-400">
  <div class="container grid items-center max-w-6xl px-2 py-2 mx-auto bg-yellow-100 lg:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-2 sm:grid-rows-2 xs:grid-rows-2">
    <div class="">
      <img src="./img/port-vector.png"
        class="scale-50"
        alt="logo">
    </div>
    <div class="text-center xs:pt-24 xs:pb-24 sm:pt-24 sm:pb-24 auto-cols-fr">
      <h1 class="text-4xl">GABRIEL STEVEN</h1>
      <h3 class="text-2xl">Front-End Web Dev, Designer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

This works fine when it is in [mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGV9W.png), but once it is expanded to larger sizes, it leaves behind extra grid cells, which results in unwanted [empty space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD70g.png). How can I get rid of these unwanted cells?

Comment: By chance, when you change from two rows to two columns, do you also reduce the number of rows to 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Saddy mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/116061040), you need to reduce the number of rows to 1 in addition to setting the columns to 2.

```html
<div class="container grid items-center max-w-6xl px-2 py-2 mx-auto bg-yellow-100 md:grid-cols-2 md:grid-rows-1 xs:grid-rows-2">
```

As a side note, you can also omit `sm:grid-rows-2` and `lg:grid-cols-2` as the changes get applied from the given breakpoint onwards (e.g., using `md:` will also apply to `lg:` and `xl:` breakpoints).